# Print out a governmental form that spans over few webforms

Tags: automation, printing, json

I would like to print an online filled forms such as form 5669 (and few other, smaller forms) at [Immigration Canada permanent resident portal](https://prson-srpel.apps.cic.gc.ca) . It can help validate them, form 5669, for instance require full work history which could be very long for some of us, and any errors could result in undesirable issues and delays in already slow immigration process.

This PR portal lets user fill each immigration form as a sequence of webform/screens, wizard style, instead of paper or pdf version, so applications can be easily processed electronically. Regretfully, there is not way to print out forms. More, even printing a webform (a section of the big immigration form) from browser is barely possible, as the navigational sidebar starts to loop. It helps to delete the sidebar using browser devtools, but it is a challenge to stretch the text to fill the page, also an immigration form include a dozen of subforms/screen so each should be visited.

Another solution is intercepting REST JSON (internal data format), massaging (e.g. removing technical properties/fields), and converting to YAML data format (which is somewhat more readable due to  lighter markup).

Will appreciate either specific solution/script or even word of advice on how to automate form printing.

If it helps the portal is implemented with Angular JS

PS. The government also make available pdf version of form, but at the moment I am not interested in using them, unless it is part of a solution of printing online, webbased forms